# Serial Downvoting not fully removed, despite flag being marked as Helpful

Tags: support, serial-voting

On the 25th of November I had this happen - each of which are questions I've asked in the past:

[image: Downvoting]

And on the 26th, 3 of those downvotes were reversed:

[image: Reversed]

I then raised a flag on one of the questions which didn't have the downvoting reversed, and it was marked as *helpful* on the same day:

[image: Flag]

Despite this, 1 week on those two non-reversed down votes still exist on these questions:

- [Is it possible to access Shadow DOM elements through the parent document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633057/is-it-possible-to-access-shadow-dom-elements-through-the-parent-document)
- [What is the most practical way to check for "@supports" support using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584228/what-is-the-most-practical-way-to-check-for-supports-support-using-only-css)

I know it's petty, considering it's only 4 points, but could these also please be removed?

Comment: So those two votes were not actually part of the series perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it'd be a bit strange getting two down votes at the same time as getting serial down voted by a different user, no? It's also worth noting that the order of the down votes matched the order of the top 5 voted questions on my profile, with "What is the logic behind sibling selectors * + * and * ~ *?" being the most voted, and "Is it possible to access Shadow DOM elements through the parent document?" being the least voted. I think that's too much of a coincidence...

Comment: Perhaps, but the serial voting reversal applies automatically and to votes by one user. If two votes were not reversed, the most likely explanation is that a separate account issued those votes. That may be troubling (indication of a sock puppet or voting ring), and perhaps that is why your flag was marked as helpful (*thanks, fraudster caught and merged or warned*). I don't know however, just speculating along and offering possible angles as to how this came to be.

Comment: I had the same thing happen last week; 5 downvotes were cast in a minute timeframe, 3 were reverted that night, and when I flagged a post of mine detailing the issue, it was simply marked as "Helpful".  I was 99% sure who the user was, since the particular user had cast 0 downvotes before I commented on a post of theirs, then suddenly their profile shows 5 downvotes after 5 of my questions and answers were downvoted, and after the reversals, they still had 2 downvotes in their profile.  For me, it's not about the points, but about the reversal system not working correctly.

Comment: I'll say that the one and only time I was serial downvoted (about a year ago), the reversal was incomplete as well.  I had 7 downvotes within 1 minute span (15:51:40 to 15:52:39), but only 5 downvotes were reversed by the script.  The initial 2 downvotes were not reversed automatically (they were reversed later manually after I flagged, but took 2 weeks).

Comment: I was serially upvoted once, and all 20 of the upvotes were promptly and completely reverted by the overnight script. Of course that's just one data point, but at least it does not seem consistently broken.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: 20 is too obvious, but I saw that 5-10 are not reverted for instance. Even funnier than that, sometimes a user admitted the serial voting outside SO via other channels and we were both looking  very very strange at the algorithm. Even worse, when this guy admitted the serial voting, the "community team" told it was not serial voting! It was really "funny" and painful simultaneously to get this answer after a "lot of investigation" from them. They clearly lack good tools, too, not just a good algorithm.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm the one who marked the flag in question as Helpful. As I think has been covered above already, the invalidation was automatic. Moderators actually cannot invalidate (or even see) individual votes. When I reviewed your flag, there *was* one thing I could do; check the relevant information moderators *can* see, and take appropriate action as far as notifying/warning/whatever. I took that action, and noted that what you reported was correct, so I marked it as Helpful.

---

I always caution against assuming anything about who voted, including extrapolating from known information. Yes; five votes in tight series, combined with three of those votes being invalidated, strongly suggests the other two may have been from the same person. But it is *absolutely possible* that's not the case.

In fact, I've seen a couple cases where the information available to me (perhaps after auto-invalidations, coupled with account deletions, user admissions, etc) showed clearly that the "other votes" came from someone else. Those two cases give me pause with these things, even.

---

That said; I do still wonder if there is some hole in this sort of thing. The exact invalidation algorithms are (properly) kept private - even from moderators - so I really do want to be careful. It's entirely possible there's something else here that makes what happened a "correct" action.

But I think this may justify a mention to the CM team, so they can have the appropriate splines reticulated, if reticulated, they must be. I would not expect any specific response back about this, necessarily, but I am mentioning it to the team to consider, just in case there's something here.