# Serial downvoting flag marked helpful but not reverted

Tags: support, serial-voting

Ok this might sound like a big reaction about a little problem:

I don't post much on SO, (6 low-level questions over the past 2 years)

2 weeks ago, I asked [one which i needed an answer for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47197999/5036612), so i added a bounty.
Half a day later, I got a downvote on almost all my old questions.

[image: Downvotes]

Now of course, those questions were not good quality but did not deserve that much hate (I'm more whining because now my question score is pretty much negative)

After waiting a few days to see it was not caught by the bot, I raised a moderator flag about it.

**The flag was marked helpful but the votes were not cancelled**

[image: helpful flag]

Do moderators not have the ability to rollback serial downvoting or is it just a mistake from the mod?

Comment: They probably had to pass it on to the CMs, who actually work for Stack Exchange. The CMs are pretty busy folks, so it might take them some time to get things handled.

Comment: Ok had not seen [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278370/5036612) which basically covers the crux of the issue: mods cannot roll back downvotes

Comment: The USA holiday last week probably did not help.  And hopefully there is a bug report involved, this should have been automatically rolled-back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Moderators can only make an initial assessment if the votes are likely to be targeted (e.g. can we see a pattern and perhaps a correlation with other events); we can't roll back votes ourselves. If there is merit in a flag, we then pass the request on to the *Community Managers* (CMs). At this point we mark the flag requesting us to look in to this as helpful if we feel there was merit in the flag. So the fact that we marked your flag as helpful means we felt it was worth forwarding the issue to the CMs for further investigation, nothing more.

The CM team will then *at some point* handle that ticket. They may decide that the votes were not targeted and not revert the votes, or they agree and revert. In your specific case, the ticket is still in the CMs queue. We don't know how long it'll take for it to be handled, or if the votes will be reverted.

Comment: do we get feedback when the ticket is handled by the CMs? whether it is rolled back or not

Comment: @Adalcar: we currently have no method to give feedback. I *usually* make this clearer when handling a flag. I'm not sure why I didn't this time, sorry about that.

Comment: @Adalcar If the votes end up getting reversed, I'm fairly sure you'll get a reputation change notification for that. If they don't reverse them, you won't get a notification.

Comment: @Adalcar JFYI, I had a similar issue, and I had flagged it. My flag was processed quite quickly (probably on the same day), but the vote reversal came ~25 days after the incident. So don't worry if it takes a bit longer. :)

Answer (score 15):

If you cast a flag because you *suspect* inappropriate behavior, such as voting fraud (or some other inappropriate behavior), as long as the mod can clearly see that the flag was cast in good faith, because you have some reasonable reason to be suspicious and to request a moderator look into it, they're going to mark the flag as helpful *even if the behavior turned out to be benign*.

The idea here is that it was appropriate of you to bring this to their attention, as it's a problem that you couldn't have investigated yourself, and they're not trying to discourage you from casting similar flags in the future if you see another similar incident that you suspect may be voting fraud.

They're only going to decline the flag if they think it's a situation *that you shouldn't have brought to their attention*, meaning it's not even something that they think they should have looked into.